# Unknown White Rectangle over canvas issue

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, paperjs

I have been working on a Floormap project using Canvas and Paper.js. I have recently come across an weird issue with canvas [image]

I keep getting these strange white boxes inside the canvas. Everything works as expected and there are no errors in the console.

also this isn't something that i added. i have seen it before when i was testing other canvas related stuff but didn't think it was a problem back then.

I am resizing the canvas dynamically depending on the device. May be that has something to do with it.

Anybody have any idea whats going on here ?

Answer (score 1):

I Have identified the Issue.

Paper.js seems to set the ViewSize property in the View during initialization and then does not seem to update it if the canvas is resized and has to be set manually after resizing the canvas.

Setting it Fixed the issue.